# x orthogonal to nonzero vectors u and v and x $\in$ Span{u,v} show x = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I can't quite figure this one out, I know that **x** $\cdot$ **u** = **0** and **x** $\cdot$ **v** = **0** and **x** = a**u** + b**v**, but I don't know how to go from there to show **x** = **0**

Comment: Take the dot product of $x = au+bv$ with $cu+dv$, which is an ordinary element in span{$u,v$}. You should get zero. So $x$ is in span{$u,v$} and it's orthogonal complement, which means that $x$ must be zero.

Answer (score 3):

You've written $\mathbf{x} = a \mathbf{u} + b \mathbf{v}$.  Good so far. What happens when you dot product both sides of this equation with $\mathbf{x}$?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}u & v\end{matrix}\right)$ with **x** both in the column space and the left null space, what does that say about **x**?

Answer (score 0):

The numeric solution was already pointed at, but imo the geometric solution is way more intuitive and easier.

$Span(u,v)$ is either a plane or a line, which $u$ and $v$ lie on. Further we know $x \perp u,v$ which means $x$ can't lie on that plane/line, unless it is zero.